# Flink Dynamic Table and Stream Connect

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to derive new table from a dynamic table and stream based on some fields.

Can someone guide best way to do this. I am new to flink and trying stuff.

```
//Dynamic Table

Table books = tEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT bookId, instrument, sum(tradedQuanity) as totalQuantity FROM tradeStreamTable group by bookId, instrument");

tEnv.registerTable("books", books);
```

BOOK

============================
BookId, Instrument, Quantity
Book1,  Goog      ,100
Book2,  Vod      ,10
Book1,  Appl      ,50
Book2,  Goog      ,60
Book1,  Vod      ,130
Book3,  Appl      ,110

```
//My Stream

tEnv.registerDataStream("allInstrumentsTable", allInstruments, "timeStampMs, instrument, instrumentValue ");
```

allInstrumentsTable

=========================================
"timeStampMs, instrument, instrumentValue(price)
Stream ......

=========================================

I am trying to derive new table(dynamic) whenever I get new change in book table or new instrumentValue for instrument in stream. join on instrument, instrumentValue * totalQuantity.

BOOK - With latest Price ( new Table )

======================================
BookId, Instrument, Quantity, instrumentValue * totalQuantity
Book1,  Goog      ,100 ,       1203
Book1,  Appl      ,50,       ...
Book1,  Vod       ,130,      ...
Book2,  Vod       ,10,       ...
Book2,  Goog      ,60,       ...
Book3,  Appl      ,110,      ...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "update" table externally. Tables in streams are like Materialized Views in RDBMS. They are derived view in a particular moment of time on the state of stream.

What you can do though is you can derive a new table from those two

```
SELECT instrument, instrumentValue * totalQuantity FROM allInstrumentsTable aJOIN books b ON a.instrument = b.instrument;
```

As this is non-windowed join you should also take into account some retention [policies](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/dev/table/streaming.html#query-configuration) to make sure the state does not grow indefinitely.

Comment: Updated question, I meant new table only. I have tried inner join but was thinking if there is other way. Left join was not working even with retention policies.